# Update menu item on login/logout

Tags: java, android

I am currently using the [material drawer library by Mike Penz](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). I have a layout and almost fully functional " basic app" so far consisting of several fragments and the navigation drawer.

I am trying to add a sticky footer item that changes based on whether the user is logged in or not. Although I have the desired effect somewhat when the user logs out the item updates but only shows upon restarting the app and vice versa on login.

As you will see in my code below my last attempt was to remove login and then add logout and vice versa but still the menu does not change until a restart.

I feel I am missing something simple but nothing I have tried nor found within Mike's website has helped. Can anyone else help?

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import com.mikepenz.fontawesome_typeface_library.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IProfile;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private static final int PROFILE_SETTING = 1;

    //save our header or result
    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;

    private IProfile profile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pref = getPreferences(0);
        goToHome();

        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_item_home);

        // Create a few sample profile
        profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mike Penz").withEmail("mikepenz@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile));

        // Create the AccountHeader
        buildHeader(savedInstanceState);

        //Create the drawer
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
            .addDrawerItems(
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1).withIdentifier(10).withSelectable(false),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_find).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_search).withIdentifier(2).withSelectable(false),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_deals).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_tag).withIdentifier(3).withSelectable(false)
            ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
            .withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View clickedView) {
                    //this method is only called if the Arrow icon is shown. The hamburger is automatically managed by the MaterialDrawer
                    //if the back arrow is shown. close the activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    //return true if we have consumed the event
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem.equals(1)) {
                        // Home
                        goToHome();
                    } else if (drawerItem.equals(2)) {
                        // Find
                        goToFind();
                    } else if (drawerItem.equals(3)) {
                        // Deals
                        goToDeals();
                    } else if (drawerItem.equals(97)) {
                        // Settings
                        goToSettings();
                    } else if (drawerItem.equals(98)) {
                        // Sign In
                        goToLogin();
                    } else if (drawerItem.equals(99)) {
                        // Invite
                        goToLogout();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
        if (pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)) {
            result.addStickyFooterItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog).withIdentifier(97).withSelectable(false));
            result.removeStickyFooterItemAtPosition(98);
            result.addStickyFooterItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_logout).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sign_out).withIdentifier(99).withSelectable(false));
        } else {
            result.addStickyFooterItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog).withIdentifier(97).withSelectable(false));
            result.removeStickyFooterItemAtPosition(99);
            result.addStickyFooterItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_login).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sign_in).withIdentifier(98).withSelectable(false));
        }

    }

    /**
     * small helper method to reuse the logic to build the AccountHeader
     * this will be used to replace the header of the drawer with a compact/normal header
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    private void buildHeader(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create the AccountHeader
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .withCompactStyle(true)
            .addProfiles(
                profile
            )
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        //add the values which need to be saved from the accountHeader to the bundle
        outState = headerResult.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
        if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
            result.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void initFragment() {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
        } else {
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void goToHome() {

        Fragment home = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, home);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void goToFind() {

        Fragment find = new FindFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, find);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void goToDeals() {

        Fragment deals = new DealsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, deals);
        ft.commit();
    }
    private void goToSettings() {

        Fragment settings = new SettingsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, settings);
        ft.commit();
    }
    private void goToLogin() {

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, login);
        ft.commit();
    }
    private void goToLogout() {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
        editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL, "");
        editor.putString(Constants.NAME, "");
        editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, "");
        editor.apply();
        goToHome();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate do not called after logout. Try change your drawer in goToLogout

```
private void refreshDrawer() {
    if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false)){

        result.removeStickyFooterItemAtPosition(..);
        result.addStickyFooterItem(..);
    }else {

        result.removeStickyFooterItemAtPosition(..);
        result.addStickyFooterItem(..);
    }
}

private void goToLogout(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
    editor.commit();
   ....
   refreshDrawer()
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this

    private void goToLogout(){
    
   ->Code to change menu here<-

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
    editor.apply();
    goToHome();
}

Comment: Thank you @Sergey Voloshyn for your help. As expected it was something simple. If I understand correctly my mistake was Java related so I will have to learn a lot more. Although your code didn't seem to work 100% as when logging out it would add menu items but not remove I managed to adjust it slightly to work.